# findelement vba

Tags: vba, selenium, xpath, selenium-chromedriver, webdriver

I am trying to fill a webelement with Selenium but can't 'reach' it. This is the code I am going to use:

```
Dim driver As New webdriver

driver.Start "Chrome"
driver.get "https://example.com"

'driver.FindElementByClass("gn_sdm_header_background").FindElementByName("searchKey").SendKeys ("abcd")
'driver.FindElementByCss("#gobtnDiv > form > table > tbody > tr > td:nth-child(3) > input[type=text]").SendKeys ("abcd")
'driver.FindElementByXPath("//*[@id=""gobtnDiv""]/form/table/tbody/tr/td[3]/input").SendKeys ("abcd")

End Sub
```

All the lines above resulted **NoSuchElementError**

Element not found for...

> 1. line: class=gn_sdm_header_background
> 2. line: Css= #gobtnDiv > form > table > tbody > tr > td:nth-child(3) > input[type=text]
> 3. line: XPath=//*[@id="gobtnDiv"]/form/table/tbody/tr/td[3]/input

And here are the parameters of the field:
[Printscreen of element-inspection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GZIg9.png)

I have no idea how to do it, so any help is greatly appreciated!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `input`  element is inside an `iframe`. you need to switch to `iframe` first, in order to access the input element.

```
driver.SwitchToFrame .FindElementByXPath("//iframe[@name='gobtn']", timeout:=10000)
driver.FindElementByXPath("//input[@name='searchKey']").SendKeys ("Test")
```

Comment: Tanks KunduK, You saved me days!